# Mail not send via send grid mailing service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

We have been using send grid mailing service on our rails app to send mail to our users. We have our app hosted on `Heroku` server, but there is an internal error as soon as rails try to send email to our users.

I looked into Heroku Logs and the error is

> Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 63ms (ActiveRecord:
>   11.1ms)2017-08-24T11:28:03.914063+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for nil port 25):

In production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain => ENV['DOMAIN'],
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

We have used `SendGrid heroku` add-on on the server so `ENV` are setup fine.
The `domain: ENV['DOMAIN']` points to domain setup on `ENV` Variable as the domain will be different on a staging server and production server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection refused error you showed is for port 25, which is the default SMTP port.

It would seem that your config is not being used. Are you sure that you are running in production environment (and not say development) and that those settings are not getting overriden by any other config file, or on a per email basis?

Using a Rails console to manually send an email and inspect all of its configuration could be useful if you cant locate the problem.